# reference_wrapper of a left reference

Tags: c++, reference, type-traits

In the following code, I try to use a vector `v1` made of references of a type and a vector `v2` made of a reference of a type:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::string  object ("foobar");
   std::string& refobj = object;

   std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<decltype(object)>> v1;

   // The following line doesn't compile => error: forming pointer to reference type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&
   std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<decltype(refobj)>> v2;
   
   std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(refobj)>>> v3;
}
```

As expected, the code compile for `v1` but not for `v2`, which should be ok as well IMHO; in such a case, the reference wrapper should do nothing since the provided type is already a reference.

Note that I can achieve what I want with vector `v3` but the code seems a little bit cumbersome.

**Question**: why the compiler is not happy while compiling `v2`? In other words, why should I first remove the type reference before adding one with `reference_wrapper` ?

Comment: " the reference wrapper should do nothing since the provided type is already a reference." but a `std::vector` cannot hold reference as elements, not directly. Thats one reason `reference_wrapper` exists

Comment: and for similar reasons you cannot have a `reference_wrapper` wrapping a reference.

Comment: I'm ok with that. Actually, my point is to know whether it is possible that ```std::reference_wrapper``` (or something derived from) could detect that the type is already a reference and in such a case apply something like I did for ```v3``` with ```std::remove_reference_t```. But it is quite possible that it goes beyond the semantics of ```std::reference_wrapper```.

Comment: you can write a trait, something like `my_reference_type<T>` that resolved to either `std::reference_wrapper<T>` or `std::reference_wrapper<remove_reference_t<T>>`. Would that fit your needs?

Comment: on the other hand, I think [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) is already doing what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words, why should I first remove the type reference before adding one with reference_wrapper ?

`reference_wrapper` does not actually "add a reference". It just emulates reference semantics, but at the same time allows to rebind the "reference". Rebinding isnt possible with references. Thats one reason why `std::reference_wrapper` exists in the first place.

Could `std::reference_wrapper` strip off the reference for you? Yes it could do the same as you did manually. However, trying to handle all types that don't match with `std::reference_wrapper` is beyond the scope of `std::reference_wrapper`. Getting a compiler error is "good enough". Moreover, it would be rather confusing when `std::reference_wrapper<T>::type` could be different from `T`.

You can use `std::ref` :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::string  object ("foobar");
   std::string& refobj = object;
   std::vector<decltype(std::ref(refobj))> v3;
}
```